# Fetching arrays using FetchedResultsController

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have the following two variables and fetch request as follows,

```
var histBooks = [String]()
var bookDescs = [String]()

let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "BookDetail")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
do
{
    let results = try context.fetch(request)
    if results.count > 0
    {
        for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
        {
            if let bookDesc = result.value(forKey: "bookTitle") as? String
            {
                bookDescs.append(bookDesc)
            }
        }
        catch{}
    }
```

I used a `for loop` to append those variables as

```
 histBooks.append(bookDescs[i])
```

Now at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` , I like to fetch the data using `fetchedResultsController`, which I am not able to figure out as it is in arrays. I can display the data as follows

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "booksTableViewCell") as! BooksTableViewCell
let bookDetail  = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.section] as! BookDetail

cell.bLabel?.text = histBooks[indexPath.row]
```

But, how do I fetch the data at `cell.bLabel?.text` using `bookDetail`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, so I will just offer the thought that, when simply displaying managed objects in a table view, it is usually not necessary to create Arrays of objects, because such arrays are available directly from Core Data – as fetched results, or the value of to-many relationships.  Can you write this code without those arrays?

Comment: If no one answers, and if my first comment does not get you moving toward a solution, please edit your question, adding an outline of your data model, including any relationships between entities.

Comment: @JerryKrinock, thanks for your reply. I can write the code without those arrays and it works. The only thing is that controllerDidChangeContent is not being called. So I thought that it is necessary to create an array of objects.

Comment: @JerryKrinock, Thanks for the tip, I was able to solve it.